# Wordpress Site Home Page not working when logged out on Hostgator

Tags: wordpress, migration

I'm working on a wordpress site, http://5twelve.church . The site is hosted on hostgator. I developed the site on 512church.com (also hosted on hostgator, same account), so that the previous site for 5twelve.church could stay live until the new one was ready (the client purchased a managed wordpress package, which Hostgator support told me provided no way for me to create any sort of subdomain site or anything like that).  Once completed, I pulled down all the theme and plugin files from 512church.com and uploaded to 5twelve.com, and then exported the database/imported the database as well. Everything appeared to be working fine - however, the site didn't work when logged out. Upon closer investigation, it looks like it's only the front page that isn't working - see  http://5twelve.church/ , but then check out http://5twelve.church/about . The about page has the theme, styled, and content - the home page is showing the default starter page that hostgator provides to an empty wordpress site. It is only doing this when logged out.

I'm very confused - does anyone have any ideas? I've spent the day on and off support with hostgator, and they've now told me several times that there is nothing they can do and that it is an issue for the web developer (which is me). I figured I'd post here and see if anyone else has had this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: what is this page: http://5twelve.church/home? you may try setting the correct template for that page (set home page template to blank) and make it the home page as explained here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: The `5twelve.church` domain name currently does not resolve at all, neither at the home page nor the about page.  The site is cached by Google for that domain though.

Comment: @ibex - Thanks for this resource - they had Home and Home FULL , using Home FULL as the main page. I renamed Home to Home ORIG and set Home FULL to Home (changed the slugs as well) and made sure it was set in the reading settings - but no luck yet.

Comment: @JustinR. - Sorry about that, the client changed the A record for a minute and it went down - it should be up now.

Comment: It looks like the page displaying for the root domain is using the 2017 theme, vs when you go to a canonical URL (like `about`), which is using your chosen theme.

Comment: Right - super weird. I ended up moving it to my own server and it worked just fine, maybe the problem was something on Hostgators end of things, although they insisted it was a development issue. Weird - working fine now though, thanks guys :)